# How can you call custom database functions with Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

If I were to define some function in the database (perhaps Postgres, or any other database):

```
create or replace function isValidCookie(ckie);
```

I would call it from SQL as:

```
select * from cookietable c where isValidCookie(c.cookie);
```

How can I call a custom function such as this from Hibernate?

Comment: I know you can use a view same as you would a table (just use mutable in the xml), but to call a function would be very handy

Comment: You may be able to do that using native queries. This [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query) explains.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to use your custom function in HQL, you'll need to define it in appropriate [Dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html)

Take a look at [PostgreSQLDialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQLDialect.html) (or any other, really) source, and you'll see a bunch of [registerFunction()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html#registerFunction(java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunction)) calls. You'll need to add one more :-) - for your own custom function.

You'll then have to specify your own dialect in Hibernate configuration.

Answer (score 7):

As of Hibernate 5, if you don't want to depend on or customize the dialect, you can define a [`MetadataBuilderInitializer`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuilderInitializer.html). For example, to use MySQL `DATE_ADD` with an `INTERVAL` from HQL, you can define a custom function called `date_add_interval`:

```
public class DateAddIntervalMetadataBuilderInitializer
        implements MetadataBuilderInitializer {
    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder,
            StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("date_add_interval",
            new SQLFunctionTemplate(DateType.INSTANCE,
                "DATE_ADD(?1, INTERVAL ?2 ?3)"));
    }
}
```

You would also need to put the name of the class in a JAR resource file called `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataBuilderInitializer`.

This approach is particularly useful when using Hibernate via a framework such as JPA and/or Spring, where the configuration is performed implicitly by the framework.

Comment: Hey I need exactly this feature to support Mariadb COLUMN_GET and TIMESTAMPDIFF functions. Currently hibernate tries to prefix the function parameters with the query alias. Where do I have to register these classes in Spring Boot?