# Hibernate Dynamic Order

Tags: hql

Hi i want to sort in HQL

```
ORDER BY IF g.groupAdminId=:adminid THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC
```

But it doesn't work, i want to have all entities where the user is admin first, how can i archieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to put named parameters outside a `where` clause.

It is possible to order according to expressions:

```
from User U
order by case
  when U.group.name = 'Admin' then 0
  when U.group.name = 'Superuser' then 1
  else 2
end asc
```

More on `case` in HQL [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) :

For your particular problem (having admins before other users) I suggest making two queries and combining the two lists in Java.

There are other ways around this but I do not like any of them:

- [Multiple mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201023/hibernate-union-alternatives)
- [Custom functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909315/how-can-you-call-custom-database-functions-with-hibernate)