# HQL order by case

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a Entity :

```
class User{
    Long id;
    String group_name;
    User head;        
}
```

I have to get ordered users in order : 
order by group_name, if user is head then first (head means than head.id = id).

I make HQL Query : `select u from User u order by u.group_name, case when u = head then 0 else 1;`
But it's not working;

In result I would like to have :
(group_name : user)

1. g1 John  (head)
2. g1 James
3. g1 Adam
4. g2 Brian  (head)
5. g2 Martin

How to make correct HQL query ?

Comment: unclear question, give more detail and give table structure if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262413/hibernate-dynamic-order

Comment: try "when u.id = head.id"

Answer (score 0):

Here is HQL query:

```
"select u.group_name from User u, User.head head where head.id=u.id order by u.group_name"
```

I didn't get what exactly from User you want since there is no column name in User class so that you can include in select part.

Comment: Sorry, but I have a ordered list by group name

Comment: I your case I got just head users, but I want to get not head user as well

Comment: "select u.group_name from User u left join User.head head where head.id=u.id order by u.group_name"  - Use this one.. it is left join which will give you both head as well as non head users as well. But then its like selecting whole User table itself.

Comment: I want to have head user at first position !!! see example in my post. g1 John (head) Head on first position .

Answer (score 0):

I would do this without grouping, by using a case statement to create a second attribute that you can order on to establish if someone is head of a group. For example:

```
select name,group_name,case when head.id is not null then 1 else 0 end as h 
from User 
order by group_name asc,h desc
```

As you can see, I have used a case statement to create an attribute h which takes the value 1 when someone is head of a group, or 0 otherwise. Then you can order on that descending, which will mean the head of each group is listed before the other members of the group.