# How do I use "order by case when ..." in HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I want to execute my HQL query like this:

```
Query queryPayment=sixSession.createQuery("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM Table1 WHERE first_name =:f_name or last_name=:l_name ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN first_name =:f_name THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
        .setParameter("first_name", f_name)
        .setParameter("last_name", l_name);
```

but it does not work. am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Names of your parameters `f_name` and `l_name`. Change this

```
setParameter("first_name", f_name)
.setParameter("last_name", l_name)
```

to this

```
setParameter("f_name", f_name)
.setParameter("l_name", l_name)
```

You can't [use named parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9284833/3405171) in the `ORDER BY`. But you can just put it using `String.format()`.