# How call the user define mysql function in Hibernate

Tags: java

I created on  function in  mysql

`SELECT mpm_autogenerate_code(param1,param2)`

and i  want to  call  this function using Hibernate Query Language

Answer (score 1):

You can use [native SQL Queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html).

Another possibility is to extend a `Dialect` as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909315/how-can-you-call-custom-database-functions-with-hibernate), but it is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You migth find [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/) tutorial useful, but it's not HQL