# How do you invoke a database function call from grails?

Tags: sql, database, grails, groovy

How do you invoke database functions from grails? 
Such as the `CONVERT(decimal, timestamp)`
Without using groovy SQL like this:

```
def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
```

I would like to avoid any SQL statements and take full advantage of the grails magic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is that grails does not have native support for database functions.  You will need to write SQL.  Gorm is an abstraction of Hibernate, you may want to refer to:

[How can you call custom database functions with Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909315/how-can-you-call-custom-database-functions-with-hibernate)

Comment: Yes, the route to take here is to have Hibernate execute the SQL, or use Groovy SQL.

Comment: I thought this might be the case but I just wanted to make sure :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your **Domain class** First you must -

**import groovy.sql.Sql**

Then you can create Sql instance and call a function like below -

```
    def date = "'21-Feb-19 14:10:10.123000'"
    def timestamp_format = "'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF'"
    String query = 'select to_timestamp('+date+','+timestamp_format+') from dual'
    def sql = Sql.newInstance('url', 'username', 'password', 'driverClassName')
    def result= sql.rows(query);
    def rows = result.collect{it.values()}
    println rows
```