# Hibernate custom query

Tags: hibernate

I found Difficult to implement the following example:

Table Location

```
Id Location longitude   latitude
1 l1        -5.938229   28.38129
2 l2        -7.389323   18.38129
3 l3        -9.378913   58.38129
```

I want o map the following query and to calculate the distance for the given by user coordinates:

```
SELECT l.*, <formula to calc distance> as distance FROM Location as l
```

I have the Location entity defined in the hbm file, but I'm don't know how to include the additional column "distance" which is not present in the default data model.

It would be handy to have this data aggregated in something like:

```
HashMap<Location, Double>
```

where the first type indicate the location and the other representes distance from the given point.

I would prefer to execute the SQL query instead of the HQL.
How this usually is achieved in the hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered defining your own dialect?

See: [How can you call custom database functions with Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909315/how-can-you-call-custom-database-functions-with-hibernate)

Alternatively, you can create a view with your desired SQL and map this view to an Hibernate Entity.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

I see you have found an answer.
Just wanted to add that a simpler alternative may be to use @PostLoad annotation on a function that populates 'distance' field.