# Average date difference using querydsl-jpa / querydsl-sql

Tags: jpql, querydsl

I'm trying to compute an average date difference using QueryDSL.

I created [a small project](https://github.com/eneveu/querydsl-sample/tree/172c376eb64650c966f510e4427dbf52a93976ef) to demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish, in a simplified manner (the real query is a lot more complex, with tons of joins / where / sort clauses). We have a [Customer](https://github.com/eneveu/querydsl-sample/blob/172c376eb64650c966f510e4427dbf52a93976ef/src/main/java/com/paradigmkick/sample/querydsl/Customer.java) class with a `birthDate` field, and we are trying to get the average age, in seconds, of our customers. We also want the maximum age, but let's focus on the average for this post.

[I tried writing this query using querydsl-jpa](https://github.com/eneveu/querydsl-sample/blob/172c376eb64650c966f510e4427dbf52a93976ef/src/test/java/com/paradigmkick/sample/querydsl/CustomerRepositoryTest.java#L62-L68), but it fails with an obscure error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$AvgFunction.determineJdbcTypeCode(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$AvgFunction.render(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:100)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.SqlGenerator.endFunctionTemplate(SqlGenerator.java:233)
        [...]
```

I also tried other approaches, like using `NumberTemplate.create(Double.class, "{0} - {1}", DateExpression.currentDate(), customer.birthDate).avg()`, but it doesn't return the correct value. If we want to get a date difference in seconds, it seems we need to find some way of calling the database-specific date/time difference functions, not just use the minus sign.

Sadly, [computing a date difference doesn't seem to be possible in JPQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991581/count-number-of-days-between-2-dates-in-jpa), so I guess querydsl-jpa has limitations there too. So we would have to write a native SQL query, or find some hack to have the QueryDsl-generated JPQL call a native database function.

[JPA 2.1 added support for invoking database functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291425/specifying-a-database-function-in-a-jpa-hibernate-namedquery), but there is a problem: the MySQL function takes the form `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2012-06-06 13:13:55', '2012-06-06 15:20:18')`. It would probably be possible if the first parameter (`SECOND`) was a String, but it seems to be a reference to some kind of constant, and it seems complicated to generate JPQL with the first parameter unquoted.

[QueryDSL added support for date differences](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/380), but it seems most of the code resides in the querydsl-sql project, so I'm wondering if I can benefit from this with querydsl-jpa.

Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to compute the average date difference using querydsl-jpa, having it maybe call the native database functions using JPA 2.1 support (maybe using `Expressions.numberTemplate()`)? Or are we forced to use querydsl-sql?
2. If we have to use querydsl-sql, how do we generate both `QCustomer` and `SCustomer`? `QCustomer` is currently generated from the Customer entity using the plugin "com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin". If I understood correctly, [I have to use a different plugin](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.2/reference/html_single/#d0e722) (com.querydsl:querydsl-maven-plugin) to generate the `SCustomer` query type?

   When looking at [querydsl-sql-example](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl-sql-example), I don't see any entity class, so I guess the query types are generated by QueryDSL from the database schema? Is there a way to generate the SCustomer query type from the entity instead, like we do with querydsl-jpa?
3. If we use querydsl-sql, is there a way to "re-use" our querydsl-jpa predicates / sorts / joins clauses in the querydsl-sql query? Or do we have to duplicate that code using querydsl-sql-specific classes?
4. I'm also considering creating a database function that delegates to `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, x, y)`, but it's not very portable...
5. Am I missing something? Is there a simpler way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using template expressions you should be able to inject any custom JPQL snippets into the Querydsl query. That should answer your first question.

Using both querydsl-jpa and querydsl-sql in the same project is possible, but adds some complexity.