# HQL doesn't allow REGEXP or RLIKE for MySQL with Hibernate 5

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, hql, hibernate-5.x

I'm trying to add **RLIKE** condition to an **HQL** query but I'm getting "**unexpected token: rlike**" error message on HQL validation.

I'm using Spring boot with Spring-data and Hibernate 5 over MySQL.

Query:

```
@Query("from PortEntity p where  p.name rlike '(gigabit)-(\\d)\\/(\\d)' ")
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"parentSlot", "parentSlot.device"})
List<PortEntity> findGigabitDevices(Pageable pageable);
```

And the error log:

```
01:26:21.033 16751 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter incident: - throwQueryException() : no errors 
01:26:21.035 16753 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.h.h.i.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl incident: - parse() - HQL: from com.***.***.entity.PortEntity p where p.name rlike '(gigabit)-(\d)\/(\d)'  
01:26:21.037 16755 [restartedMain] ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter incident: - line 1:75: unexpected token: rlike 
01:26:21.043 16761 [restartedMain] ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter incident: - line 1:75: unexpected token: rlike 
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: rlike
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:784)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:316)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:198)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:283)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:546)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:655)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy152.createQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:144)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:212)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
```

I've discovered that in new Hibernate versions, HQL is parsed via ANTLR-based parser, and it's grammar just doesn't have **REGEX** or **RLIKE** keywords:
[Hibernate HQL ANTLR grammar](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6ba328e7a03d2faaf648e85310e903f11211cbd8/hibernate-core/src/main/antlr/hql.g)

I've tried to switch to the classical HQL parser by adding Hibernate property

```
"hibernate.query.factory_class" = "org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory"
```

but in this case @EntityGraph stops working with message "EntityGraphs cannot be applied queries using the **classic QueryTranslator**":

```
01:56:59.412 91498 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver incident:REQID3302215661531 - Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: EntityGraphs cannot be applied queries using the classic QueryTranslator!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: EntityGraphs cannot be applied queries using the classic QueryTranslator!
```

Should something be configured to allow RLIKE / REGEXP usage in Hibernate 5 with ANTLR-based parser, or it's bug?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to use MySQL rlike function in Hibernate we need to create a "SQLFunctionTemplate".

Now, how to do it:

First: Create a class called "AppMySQLDialect" and extends from MySQLDialect then override the empty constructor and finally register the regexp function:

```
public class AppMySQLDialect extends MySQLDialect {
    public AppMySQLDialect() {
        super();
        /**
         * Function to evaluate regexp in MySQL
         */
        registerFunction("rlike", new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.INTEGER, "?1 rlike ?2"));
    }
}
```

Ok, now lets use it as follow:

```
FROM PortEntity p where rlike(p.name, '(gigabit)-(\\d)\\/(\\d)') = 1
```

Create your HibernateQuery and execute.

**For Hibernate 5 you can check this:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/41369853/1715121

Comment: Unfortunately, seems it doesn't work for Hibernate 5.
As I'm aware, dialect is responsible for generating SQL, but not parsing HQL.
Also, Hinernate.Integer was deprecated in 3.6

Comment: You're setting the new dialect  `AppMySQLDialect` in your Hibernate configuration?

Comment: Yes, I've double checked the solution you've suggested, but I got same ANTLR parsing error.

Comment: Also has no effect :(
It seems to me, the problem is not related to dialect or SQL generation, because Hibernate just cannot parse HQL.
I've debugged org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser and seems it's just a bug. There's no code that checks for registered functions there. I'll try to fire a bug in the Hibernate tracker.

Comment: Thanks. For anyone trying to use this in future, you also need to set the custom class in the Hibernate properties:  <persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="utils.AppMySQLDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's just not possible.
Hibernate 5 doesn't work with HQL, but works with JPQL that has a standard.
And this standard (implemented by ANTLR parser) just doesn't declare REGEXP / RLIKE support.

[JPQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html)