# Is there a way to get the hour difference between 2 dates in Hibernate HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I looked through many answers but couldn't find one that actually works with pure HQL. Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: With pure HQL I think it's not possible. HQL is limited by the Ansi SQL and there is no complex date functions specified for the pattern, so every database has his own customized date functions. But you can register the native database function and call it with HQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909315/how-can-you-call-custom-database-functions-with-hibernate