# How to use SAMPLE Keyword in query using QueryDSL

Tags: querydsl

**sample_clause**

**The sample_clause lets you instruct the database to select from a random sample of data from the table, rather than from the entire table.**

I want to run below query using QueryDSL

sample_clause

The sample_clause lets you instruct the database to select from a random sample of data from the table, rather than from the entire table.

select  from Test t SAMPLE(80) **WHERE t.test_id=01 and t.test_suite_id=02**;

where the condition is dynamic and I am generating it using queryDSL however I don't know how to add the SAMPLE keyword to query DSL.

```
public Long getCount(TestDTO testDTO) {
    JPAQuery<Tuple> query = new JPAQuery<>(entityManager);
    QTest qTest=QTest.test;
    //dynamic where condition.
    OptionalBooleanBuilder where = buildCondition(testDTO);
    
    List<BigDecimal> output=query
            .select(qTest.testId)
            .from(qTest)
            .where(where.build()).fetch();
   //finally return the output.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SAMPLE` is a database dialect specific function that is not available in JPQL, the query language of JPA. As such, you need to register a custom function for your dialect with your ORM implementation. You could register these functions yourself using [custom functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41369853/2104280).

However, after this, these functions still won't be accessible in QueryDSL. In order to do so, you'd have to implement a custom `Operation` implementation and associate it with a "template" in a subclass of `JPQLTemplates`. Alternatively, you could create a `TemplateExpression` inline: `Expressions.template(Integer.class, "SAMPLE({0})", arg1)`.