# How to use rownum in querydsl

Tags: mysql, querydsl

[image]

[image]

How do I use the rownum in the above situation?

DataBase : Mysql

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

`SqlExpressions.rowNumber()` returns a `ROW_NUMBER()` expression. Keep in mind that this only works in `querydsl-sql` and not in `querydsl-jpa`, because JPQL (the query language for JPA) itself lacks support for window functions (and so do proprietairy JPQL extensions such as Hibernates HQL).

In order to use `ROW_NUMBER` inside JPA queries, a custom function must be registered for your ORM provider. You could register these functions yourself using [custom functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41369853/2104280).

After registering your custom function, you will still have to extend `JPQLTemplates` to include the template for your custom window function.

You'd do this like this:

```
public class MyTemplates extends JPQLTemplates {

    public MyTemplates() {
        add(SQLOps.ROWNUMBER, "ROW_NUMBER({0})");
    }

}
```

And then use it as follows:

```java
new JPAQuery(entityManager, new MyTemplates()).from(entity).select(rowNumber())
```

With the Spring integration in the middle however, the templates are somewhat more difficult to bind to the query I think.

---

Alternatively you could look into the [`blaze-persistence-querydsl`](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/core/manual/en_US/#querydsl-integration) extension, which has out of the box support for window functions (and many other features) for JPQL. For example:

```java
QCat cat = QCat.cat;

BlazeJPAQuery<Tuple> query = new BlazeJPAQuery<Tuple>(entityManager, criteriaBuilderFactory).from(cat)
    .select(cat.name, JPQLNextExpressions.rowNumber(), JPQLNextExpressions.lastValue(cat.name).over().partitionBy(cat.id));

List<Tuple> fetch = query.fetch();
```